# React Router - new component not being loaded

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

So it's my first time setting something like this up and I'm struggling a little bit.

I used https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/tree/master/examples/huge-apps as my source of learning and am trying to set up a very basic layout for a react application.

What seems to be happening is that react isn't re-rendering after a path change therefore nothing ever gets added to the dom

When I click on the go to home component Link the URL bar changes but no DOM changes occur...

Here is my code [i'm leaving out my directory structure since i don't think it's important for the problem]

---

**index.jsx**: Load up the react app and get all routes

```
import 'babel-polyfill';
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import { Router, browserHistory } from 'react-router';

import Routes from './app/Routes.js';

render(
  <Router
    history={browserHistory}
    routes={Routes}
  />,
  document.querySelector('.js-mount-point')
);
```

**Routes.js**: Constant to keep all of my routes so that I don't have to manually specify them in index.js

```
import App from './App.jsx';
import Home from '../routes/Home/Home.js';

const Routes = {
  path: '/',
  component: App,
  childRoutes: [
    Home,
  ],
};

export default Routes;
```

**App.jsx**: Parent most component for my app

```
import React from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router';

const App = props => {
  console.log(props);
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Hello World!</h1>
      <p><Link to="#/home">Go to Home Component</Link></p>
      {props.children} 
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

**Home.js** Grab all my route information and getComponent lives here

```
const HomeRoute = {
  path: 'home',
  title: 'Home',
  getComponent(nextState, cb) {
    require.ensure([], (require) => {
      cb(null, require('./HomeComponent.jsx').default);
    });
  },
};

export default HomeRoute;
```

**HomeComponent.jsx** my very basic home component

```
import React from 'react';
```

---

```
const HomeComponent = () => (
    <div>
      <h2>Welcome Home</h2>
    </div>
);

export default HomeComponent;
```

Edit1: Made App.jsx pure function

Edit2: Fixed Routes.js

Edit3: Fixed Home.js

Edit4: Final fix,

```
const HomeComponent =
```

changed to

```
const HomeComponent = () => (
```

Comment: "Edit1: Made App.jsx pure function" you don't. What is `render` doing there? Did you mean `return`?

Comment: @YuryTarabanko ah man copied the wrong version of my code... gimme a sec

Comment: You actually don't need `render` anywhere expect for `index.jsx` file.

Comment: Fix `HomeRoute`. Path should be `home`. And links should be `<Link to="home">Blah Blah</Link>`.

Comment: @YuryTarabanko new error with all the changes: warning.js:44Warning: React.createElement: type should not be null, undefined, boolean, or number. It should be a string (for DOM elements) or a ReactClass (for composite components). Check the render method of `RouterContext`.

Comment: Check `HomeComponent` it should be a function `const HomeComponent = () ****=>**** (..)`

Comment: Never mind! It used const x = ( .. ) instead of const x = () => ( ... )

Thanks @YuryTarabanko for the awesoem help!!! :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You `App` should be a component not a function returning an object. Right now you are mixing two approaches.

Either a function (stateless component)

```
import React from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router';

const App = props => {
    console.log(props.children);
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Hello World!</h1>
        <p><Link to="/home">Go to Home Component</Link></p>
        {props.children} 
      </div>
    );
};

export default App;
```

Or a statefull component that has `render` method

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router';

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    console.log(this.props.children);
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Hello World!</h1>
        <p><Link to="/home">Go to Home Component</Link></p>
        {this.props.children} 
      </div>
    );
  }
};

export default App;
```

Same with `HomeComponent`

```
const HomeComponent = () => (
    <div>
      <h2>Welcome Home</h2>
    </div>
);
```

And you need to fix route config as well

```
const HomeRoute = {
  path: 'home', //no # needed
  title: 'Home',
  getComponent(nextState, cb) {
    require.ensure([], (require) => {
      cb(null, require('./HomeComponent.jsx').default);
    });
  },
};
```

Ohh, and I think you need.

```
const Routes = {
  path: '/',
  component: App,
  childRoutes: [
    Home
  ],
};
```

Comment: I changed my App into a stateless component now but It's still behaving the same way? props.children still returns null but props.route.childRoutes does contain an array of objects with my routes

Comment: Have you fixed `HomeComponent`? The code you have now makes no sense.

Comment: @RobertCrous , you need to fix routes config as well.

Comment: Okay I'm getting a new error now that App.jsx is a stateless component:
_renderNewRootComponent(): Render methods should be a pure function of props and state; triggering nested component updates from render is not allowed. If necessary, trigger nested updates in componentDidUpdate. Check the render method of App.

Comment: @RobertCrous You don't need to call render from within stateless component. Actually you need to call it once with root component (Router in your case).

Comment: aha okay I understand now! But the thing that confuses me is what I Need to fix in Route Config, apart from the # it doesn't look like anything has changed

Comment: You don't need `#`. First of all you are using `browserHistory` that utilizes HTML5 History API. And even if it fallbacks to `hashchange` router will add hashes automagically.

Comment: @Yuri but refresh still kills the entire app if you don't setup an htaccess to rewrite urls on load, unless I'm missing a module that does that without the mission of .htaccess (using browsersync for dev)